Get all Azure policy definitions related to customer managed keys using PowerShell or ArmClient
I want to automate the process of listing all policies in Azure that support Customer-managed keys for Azure Storage encryption.
Right now my current approach is to search for them in the Azure portal directly. I want to automate this process to check on this status frequently. Some quick approaches I see are to use either PowerShell or C# and the ArmClient API to query the policyDefinitions based on a string match. This string match does not account for edge cases like if the acronym "CMK" is used or if the text of the description changes potentially under different languages.
Wondering if there is a more scalable approach or any alternatives that anyone can share?
PowerShell potential option:
Get-AzPolicyDefinition | Where-Object { $_.Properties.Description -like "*customer managed keys*"}

Potential endpoint I can call from an API:
"/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/policyDefinitions?$filter=properties/description+contains+'customer+managed+keys'"


The command you are using is not valid for fetching the definitions with descriptions that match the given text."
The Description property is not under the Properties section, so it can be called directly.
When I use the same script, it does not fetch any definitions
Output:

You can use the below cmdlet to fetch the Azure policy definitions where the description matches the text customer managed keys, regardless of its position in the text.
Get-AzPolicyDefinition | Where-Object { $_.Description -like "*customer managed keys*" } | Format-List

After running the command, Policy definitions with the description text 'customer managed keys' are displayed.
Output:


I wonder if reading the policy rules instead could be a stronger way to determine this rather than a string match? For example, I see some policies have the policyRule called "field": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/encryption.keySource",  or "field": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/encryption.state",., which seem to strongly imply the use of customer managed keys.

The feild type parameter is not available for checking the field; it only supports displayed parameters.
